# ReactNative How to set Text component text vertical center

Tags: react-native

When React Native `Text` component's height is higher than text(inside Text), text will be topping (vertical align top) and cannot be set vertical align center.

It is like this picture. (Inspect `Text` component)

[image]

```
<View style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItem: 'center', height: 96 }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 32 }}>Select</Text>
</View>
```

`display: 'flex'` worked in `View` component but it doesn't work `Text` component.
So, I don't know how to set vertical align center.

Only one way I know is set `height` size in `Text` component but it is not a good way...

I want to know correct way to set vertical align for `Text` component.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItem: 'center' }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 32 }}>Select</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Add `justifyContent: 'center'` in your View style. Modify your code like this :

```js
<View style={{ height: 96, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 32 }}>Select</Text>
</View>
```